# html and php file coming back empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I separated my files into geolocation.html and test.php. I used Ajax to pass variables var latitude and longitude to use in my php file but both are coming back empty. Don't really need the div just want to be able to use longitude and latitude in my php file. Do I need to put something in my success function,do a function call? What am I missing?
geolocation.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "js/jquery.js" > </script>
<script>

//javascript is on the client
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}


function showPosition(position) {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     //Pass longitude and latitude to php how?
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {lat: latitude,lng:longitude},
        success: function(data) {
            /*Pass longitude and latitude to php*/
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}

</head>     
<body onload="getLocation()">
<div id="content"></div> 
</body>
```

Now test.php file

```
<?php 
 // $addlat = $_GET['addlat'];
 // $addlong = $_GET['addlong'];
 if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) )  {
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    echo $lat." ".$lng  ; 
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing `</script>` before `</head>`

Comment: change data: {lat: latitude,lng:longitude} TO data: {'lat': latitude,'lng':longitude}

Comment: Why do you call **jQuery** twice?
Use either
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
or
`<script type= "text/javascript" src= "js/jquery.js"></script>`
but not both

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code

HTML/PHP FILE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(redirectToPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function redirectToPosition(position) {
    //window.location='weather.php.php?lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&long='+position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
     url: 'vuetest/testajax',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
     success : function(resp) {
      console.log(resp)
     }
    })
    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

SERVER SIDE

```
public function testajax()
    {
        print_r($_POST);
      // Here you can check and use variables
    }
```

Comment: You should include an explanation about why the OP should try this. What have you changed and why? You should probably also mention that this code is for _debugging_  and not for copy/paste to make it work.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. But I still can't use my  variables in my .php file

Comment: Also, your example of the server side code seem to be a class method for some reason? What class is that and where would that get called? The OP doesn't mention any framework or similar...

Comment: @IsmailIssa How can you be so sure?

Comment: Well in my html file the long and lat are outputting to div but when I refresh php page comes back empty(after going through html)

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly worked for me.

1. I removed one of the jQuery includes.
2. I used the jQuery *$(document).ready()* instead of the body *onload* event.

HTML FILE

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //javascript is on the client
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        //Pass longitude and latitude to php how?
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {lat: latitude,lng:longitude},
            success: function(data) {
                /*Pass longitude and latitude to php*/
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getLocation();
    });
    </script>
</head>   
<body>
    <div id="content"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) )  {
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    echo $lat." ".$lng  ; 
}
?>
```